# getting error : pre-receive hook declined while deploying Vue Project on Heroku

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, npm

I am using Windows 10. By following the tutorial here, I tried to deploy a Vue Application named "GreenField", I have created Heroku account, installed GIT and Heroku successfully and added heroku to my system PATH.

After that, I did the following thing:

---------- FIRST (successful)-------------

```
$ cd PATH/TO/MY_APP  
$ git init  
$ git add .  
$ git commit -m "1st attempt"
```

------------THEN (successful)-----------

```
$ heroku create

//logged in to the heroku  

Created  https://git.heroku.com/greenfield-demo.git  
Git remote heroku added
```

----------- LAST (Which failed!!!)----------

```
$ git push heroku master  

Enumerating objects: 106, done.  
Counting objects: 100% (106/106), done.  
Delta compression using up to 4 threads  
Compressing objects: 100% (104/104), done.  
Writing objects: 100% (106/106), 9.04 MiB | 92.00 KiB/s, done.  
Total 106 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0  
remote: Compressing source files... done.  
remote: Building source:  
remote:  
remote: -----> Node.js app detected  
remote:  
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment  
remote:  
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error  
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true  
remote:        YARN_PRODUCTION=true  
remote:        NODE_ENV=production  
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true  
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false  
remote:  
remote: -----> Installing binaries  
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  >=10.0.0  
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   >=6.0.0 
remote:  
remote:        Resolving node version >=10.0.0...  
remote:        Downloading and installing node 14.9.0...  
remote:        Bootstrapping npm >=6.0.0 (replacing 6.14.8)...  
remote:        npm >=6.0.0 installed  
remote:  
remote: -----> Installing dependencies  
remote:        Installing node modules  
remote:  
remote:        > core-js@3.6.5 postinstall /tmp/build_fba00100/node_modules/core-js  
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"  
remote:  
remote:        added 62 packages in 2.5s  
remote:  
remote: -----> Build  
remote:        Running build  
remote:  
remote:        > mcdonalds@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_fba00100  
remote:        > vue-cli-service build  
remote:  
remote: sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found  
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
remote: npm ERR! syscall spawn  
remote: npm ERR! file sh  
remote: npm ERR! errno ENOENT  
remote: npm ERR! mcdonalds@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`  
remote: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT  
remote: npm ERR!  
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the mcdonalds@0.1.0 build script.  
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output   above.  
remote:  
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:  
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.v7hlp/_logs/2020-09-04T15_17_46_001Z-debug.log  
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed  
remote: 
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:  
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys  
remote:  
remote:        Some possible problems:  
remote:   
remote:        - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node  
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version  
remote:  
remote:        Love,  
remote:        Heroku  
remote:  
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.  
remote:  
remote:  !     Push failed  
remote: Verifying deploy...  
remote:  
remote: !       Push rejected to greenfield-demo.  
remote:  
To https://git.heroku.com/greenfield-demo.git  
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)  
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/greenfield-demo.git'  
Windows@DESKTOP-C57FL9F MINGW64 /e/projects/ValueLabs Projects/vue/mcdonalds (master)
```

high-sunrise-58.git'
As you see above, my LAST step failed.

What could be the possible reason for the error in my LAST step(when push my app to Heroku)?Why it is failed?